# HP Pavilion Qualcomm WiFi not working in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 17.04, hp

I have read a lot of posts about this problem, but none of them seems to fix my problem, I have a Qualcomm network adapter in my HP Pavilion dv4 and it worked just fine in Windows. Also, when I installed Ubuntu server it gave me the same problem. [Here is my pastebin with my network diagnostics.](https://pastebin.com/FhW4T1g0) And I will paste some additional tests down below. Any help is appreciated. My Ubuntu version is 17.04.

```
lspci:

08:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

iwconfig:

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

P.S. I have already checked if it is in airplane mode and tried to turn on the WiFi but it immediately turns itself OFF.